# Utf8 encoding makes me confused

Tags: unicode, utf-8

```
let buf1 = Buffer.from("3", "utf8");

let buf2 = Buffer.from("Здравствуйте", "utf8");

// <Buffer 33>

// <Buffer d0 97 d0 b4 d1 80 d0 b0 d0 b2 d1 81 d1 82 d0 b2 d1 83 d0 b9 d1 82 d0 b5>
```

Why does char '3' encode to '33' in buf1 but 'd0 97' in buf2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `3` is not `З`, despite the similarity to the untrained eye. Look closer and you'll see the difference, however subtle.

The former is Unicode code point `U+0033 - DIGIT THREE` (see [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0033/index.htm)), while the latter is `U+0417 - CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ZE` (see [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0417/index.htm)), encoded in UTF-8 as `d0 97`.

The Russian word is actually hello, pronounced (*very* roughly, since I only *know* hello and goodbye, taught by a Russian girlfriend *many* decades ago) "Strasvoytza", with no "three" anywhere in the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The first character of the second buffer is the Cyrillic character "Ze" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ze_(Cyrillic) and not the Arabic numeral 3 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3